# IdentityServer event for token cleanup

Tags: identityserver4

I would like to know if there is an event that fired in the IdentityServer 4 framework when token cleanup job runs?

I have wrapped a third party system into the IdentityServer framework and need to notify the third party system to cleanup user sessions when the tokens in IdentityServer are no longer valid... mostly due to token is expired.

Any suggestions or examples?

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not exist right now. Open a feature request on the github [issue tracker](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues) please.

Comment: Thank you.. if I worked on PR, would this work be considered for contribution?

Comment: open an issue first

Answer (score 0):

For future references, you need to implement `IOperationalStoreNotification` and include it in the DI

```cs
public class MyOperationalStoreNotification : IOperationalStoreNotification
{
    public Task PersistedGrantsRemovedAsync(IEnumerable<PersistedGrant> persistedGrants) 
    {
        // ... put your code here
    }
}
```